# How to call a Java class from a background thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to call this class from a background thread.

```
ChartPenData.main(arguments);
```

How can I do that?

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
thread = ChartPenData.main(arguments);
thread.run();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {ChartPenData.main(arguments);}
}.start();
```

But better to have a class implement runnable, which takes arguments as constructor parameters, and store it as member variable to use inside run() method.
Then you would do:

```
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```

Comment: where would he get arguments from?

Comment: since Thread is anonymous & inline, it can see variables outsides its scope

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        ChartPenData.main(arguments);
    }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: where would he get arguments from?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest safe way to do that is using java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.

You can use java.util.concurrent.Executors utility methods to create ExecutorService's

example:

```
 private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 executorService.submit( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ChartPenData.main(arguments);                
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a fair idea about what you are trying to achieve

```
    public class Tester {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
          String[] arguments = {"param1", "param2"};
          Thread t = new Thread(new ClassCaller(arguments));
          t.start();
       }
    }

    class ClassCaller implements Runnable {
       private String[] arguments;
       public ClassCaller(String[] args) {
          arguments = args;
       }
       public void run() {
         ChartPenData.main(arguments);
       }
    }

class ChartPenData {
//your class code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code doesn't make much sense:

- It creates a `Thread` that doesn't do anything.
- It assigns the same variable two times without ever using the value of the variable in between.
- It calls a function as if the function was going to *return* a `Thread` (and, I'm guessing from the name of the function that that's not what it does) when you say you want to call the function *in* a thread.

Other answers here show you what you asked for, but IMO, you would be better off learning more of the basics of Java (classes, types, variables, method calls, etc.) before you attempt to learn anything about threads.